# error handling with celebrate not working properly

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, middleware

I have the following route in graphql.ts

```
export const router = express.Router();
router.post(
  '/graphql',
  celebrate({
    [Segments.HEADERS]: Joi.object({
      authorization: Joi.string().required(),
    }).unknown(),
    [Segments.BODY]: Joi.object({
      query: Joi.string().required()
    }).unknown()
  }),
  async (req, resp, err) => {
    const data = await fetchGraphql(req.headers.authorization, req.body);
    resp.json(data);
  }
);
```

and in index.ts, I do the following

`app.use(errors());`

This doesnt work properly, and it throws the error in the console instead of sending it as a request, and I get the error like `Error: celebrate request validation failed`

However, when I attach this post request to the `app` directly (`app.post(..)`) or when I use `router.use(errors());` in the graphql.ts file, it works and I get the JSON response